# Global name 'displayhtml' is not defined

Tags: django

I'm trying to implement the google reCAPTCHA plugin into my form by following this tutorial http://blog.bixly.com/post/4069885657/how-to-add-recaptcha-to-your-django-forms

The steps look straight forward

```
Here are the steps to make it work:

1.Obtain a public and a private key.
2.Download a plugin for python.
3.Render the widget in the form page.
4.Verify the answer by sending a request to google’s server.
5.Check the response.
```

But when I get to step 3 in render the widget in the form page . I get this error. From reading the tutorial it doesn't refer me to import anything . Can someone help me

**Rendering the widget
The modules that you need from the plugin reside in recaptcha.client.captcha. It contains a method called displayhtml() that returns a string of javascript code which you use to render the widget. Here is a sample usage:**

```
 NameError at /account/forgot-password/

 global name 'displayhtml' is not defined
 Request Method:    GET
 Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/forgot-password/
 Django Version:    1.4.3
 Exception Type:    NameError
 Exception Value:   

 global name 'displayhtml' is not defined

 Traceback:
 File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
   111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 File "C:\o\17\mysite\accounts\views.py" in forgot_password
   12.      script = displayhtml(public_key=public_key)

 Exception Type: NameError at /account/forgot-password/
 Exception Value: global name 'displayhtml' is not defined
```

Here are the steps to make it work:

```
Obtain a public and a private key.
Download a plugin for python.
Render the widget in the form page.
Verify the answer by sending a request to google’s server.
Check the response.
```

my views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import password_reset
from django.shortcuts import render
from mysite.settings import *

def forgot_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return password_reset(request,
            from_email=request.POST.get('email'))

    else:
        public_key = 'DAAW231rf2ef23rfq'
        script = displayhtml(public_key=public_key)
        return render(request, 'forgot_password.html',{'script':script})
```

template

```
  <form>
    {{ form }}{% csrf_token %}
    {{ script }}
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the module from where you get the `displayhtml()` function from.

```
from somemodule import displayhtml
```

Comment: oh great , some tutorial . they don't even tell you to import anything or add anything in installed_app . :(